# Use netcat to send UDP packets out 1 ethernet port and into another on the same server

Tags: networking, ethernet, netcat

I am trying to sanity check a network device and want to use netcat to send upd traffic out a specific ethernet port (eth0 for example) and receive that packet on a different port on the same system (eth1 for example) with an ethernet cable connecting them.
I set both ethernet devices to the same subnet, but when I try to use netcat, I see the data but when I unplug the ethernet cable, I still see the data meaning it isn't traveling out of the ports.  How do I force netcat to use a specific ethernet device?  Is there a way to do this using only a single server?

Answer (score 0):

Phemmer has a [great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368690/why-netcat-doesnt-use-the-right-interface-associated-with-the-ip) to walk you through how to do this, but I'm going to paraphrase for visibility:

Since you're using the IP address, netcat uses whatever interface it wants based on routing tables. Since you are connecting to the same host (based on ip), the server just uses the loopback adapter `lo` instead of `eth0` or `eth1`. Using `socat` or adding routes is the way to solve this issue (See link).